# Trying to publish and sync table from excel into sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-addin, excel

I have created a table in excel and would like to sync it with sharepoint. I have downloaded `SynchronizeWSSandExcel.xlam` to allow me to publish and sync the table to sharepoint.

When I click the Publish and sync button I am prompted with a box with 3 sections; Address, name and description.

I fill these sections out but then get an error saying

> Can not connect to the server

From reading similar posts regarding this topic, it would seem that what I enter into the Address and name section are critically important. However, the specifics of what exactly goes in there seems to vary from post to post.

Does anyone know exactly what I need to put into these boxes?

Comment: In address : SharePoint Site URL and in Name : Name of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Address : SharePoint Site url where you want sync it with Sharepoint
         **Example :** http://xyx.com/sites/yoursitename/

Name    : Name of List which will be created in Sharepoint site with sync data
         from excel.
        **Example** : MyTableSyncFromExcel

Description : Its the information which you want to provide list.

**Please Note :**  It will work if you create a list from scratch.Existing SharePoint list can not be used.

Edit

In address you can put either http://cnet/en-uk/ or http://cnet/

Try this

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bhaskar! For the address, I do the full URL of the page where I want the table to be? Is the name of the list something I produce myself? Cheers

Comment: You just need to provide site name only and the list name. It will create a list in your SharePoint Site. Then you can add the list to the page wherever you want.

Comment: when you say site name, that refers to the homepage of my sharepoint site? as opposed to a particular page. The name, then is just an arbritary name that I produce myself? Thank you

Comment: Yes you are right. But do not give complete home page url. You can remove the part after site name. You can refer example for site url in my answer.

Comment: If you can share your home page url. I will tell you what needs to use exactly.

Comment: Thank you Bhaskar! I was just on my lunch..the homepage url is

Comment: http://cnet/en-uk/Pages/default.aspx

Comment: remove page/default.aspx and put remaining url as Address. Let me know if it works.

Comment: sadly it does not work, I keep getting the same error message   ' Cannot connect to the server at this time. Your table cannot be published ' Just to clarify again, the 'name' section can be anything? Cheers Bhaskar!

Comment: Yes it can be anything. It will become name of list. Can you update your question with complete site home page url. Starting from h t t p

Comment: Frank , I tried this by myself . It works fine for me. Definitely there is something wrong with your address. Update the question with complete site url and I will try to provide address for you from it. Else you can play around with site url just by removing one one part from the end.

Comment: Thanks Bhaskar, the full URL is as follows; http://cnet/en-uk/Pages/default.aspx     When you tried what URL did you use? Cheers

Comment: sorry I have just looked at this again, I did type http:// but it did not show up,    so just before cnet there is http://

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33920/discussion-between-bhaskar-dhone-and-frankwhite).